# Creating a Hierarchical Grid from a single query

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, syncfusion

Given the below query how would I create a Hierarchical Grid on "salesPriceNo" so that the Parent Grid would show  all "h" data and the Child Grid would show all "d" data?  I found the following in the, Common User Guide, but it makes no mention of WebForms.

```
SELECT h.salesPriceNo, h.customerNo, h.status, h.itemNo, h.salesPersonCode, d.salesPriceDtlNo, d.salesPriceNo, d.itemNo, d.qtyPer, d.unitCost
FROM salesPriceHeader h LEFT OUTER JOIN salesPriceDetail d ON h.salesPriceNo = d.salesPriceNo
WHERE h.customerNo = 'MyCustomerNo12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Syncfusion ASP.Net Grid` control don’t have in-built support to use Hierarchical Grid feature. But we can achieve your requirement with the `DetailsTemplate` feature of the grid. Details Template feature provides a detailed view about additional information of each row by expanding the row.

We can achieve your requirement in the following ways. Please refer the below code snippet.

```
<ej:Grid id="Grid" runat="server" DetailsTemplate="#childgridtemplae">         
     <Columns>
         <ej:Column Field="salesPriceNo" HeaderText="SalesPrice NO"/>
         <ej:Column Field="customerNo" HeaderText="Customer No"/>                             
         <ej:Column Field="status" HeaderText="Status"/>
         <ej:Column Field="itemNo" HeaderText="Item No"/>
         <ej:Column Field="SalesPersonCode" HeaderText="SalesPerson Code"/>                          
     </Columns>
     <ClientSideEvents DetailsDataBound="onDetailsDataBound" />
  </ej:Grid>
```

At the code behind, the data obtained using the query(asked in question) can be assigned to parent grid as follows.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 this.Grid.DataSource = (DataTable)GetData();//Return data from join operation
 this.Grid.DataBind();
 }
```

In the above you can see that the top level grid will contains the columns from  `salesPriceHeader` table and  the detailsTemplate used to display the child grid is as follows.

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="childgridtemplae">
    <div id="SaleChildGrid{{:salesPriceNo}}" class="e-childgrid" ></div>
</script>
```

The id of the child grid is generated dynamically based on the salesPriceNo field.

Now in the `detailsDataBound` event the child grid will be rendered as follows.

```
function onDetailsDataBound(e) {

        e.detailsElement.find(".e-childgrid").ejGrid({
            dataSource: this.model.dataSource, //Parents data source
            columns: [
            { field: "salesPriceDtlNo", headerText: "SalesPrice Dlt No" },
            { field: "salesPriceNo", headerText: "SalesPrice No" },
            { field: "itemNo", headerText: "Item No" },
            { field: "qtyPer", headerText: "Quantity" },
            { field: "unitCost", headerText: "Unit Cost" }
            ]
        });
    }
```

In the above event handler you can notice that the child grid contains the columns from `salesPriceDetail` table and also parents data source is provided directly to the child datasource since the join operation is performed at the server and hence no filtering is required at the client side to get details grid data. And now the parent and child grid are rendered using same datasource with columns from `salesPriceHeader` (h) are showed in parent grid and `salesPriceDetail`(d) are displayed in child grid.

[DetailsTemplate Demo](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/grid/detailtemplate.aspx)